# Can anyone explain what are these parameters for this function?

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, ecdsa, ecdh

int EC_POINT_set_compressed_coordinates_GFp
(const EC_GROUP *group, EC_POINT *p,
const BIGNUM *x, int y_bit, BN_CTX *ctx);

I just want to set the randomly generated ECDH public key as the X9.62 compressed
coordinate of a point over GFp for group P-256 , assuming 0 as the y-bit.

but that randomly generated ECDH public key is in hex string(already converted to some format to hex string)?

Comment: Assuming a usual C string (char array terminated by null byte), use **BN_hex2bn** to convert hex string to BIGNUM object.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085 for responding. yes I converted to BIGNUM object.
const EC_GROUP *group, EC_POINT *p, const BIGNUM *x, int y_bit, BN_CTX *ctx

if you tell me what are the parameters I have take for the function, That would be more helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are all described on the man page (note: read from the paragraph on EC_point_set_affine_coordinates through the ones on EC_point_set_compressed_coordinates because they are interrelated) except for ctx which is described on the man page for BN_CTX_{new,free,...} and which for a single call you don't need (just pass NULL).